# Прямая речь или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли оформлено предложение или лучше обойтись без кавычек?

Ответ  на  вопрос  «Что  делать  в  этой  ситуации?»  заложен  в  каждом  из  вышеприведенных  выводов.

Или:

Ответ  на  вопрос, что  делать  в  этой  ситуации,  заложен  в  каждом  из  вышеприведенных  выводов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужны кавычки без запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос: «Что делать в этой ситуации?» -- заложен в каждом из вышеприведенных выводов.

или:

Ответ на вопрос «Что делать в этой ситуации?» заложен в каждом из вышеприведенных выводов.